# What's the best/correct way to store data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm working now on a project that involves many users and they're log in time/log out time (and summary) details. To be able to watch after their presence.
My question is what is possibly the best way to store tat data? (if we talk about hundreds or maybe thousands of users)
1. To make an DB that contains a table for each user, there it has all the dates and hours?
2. To make one big table which contains all this data?

Thanks.

Comment: One table for all users.

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: You don't want different queries for each user. You may want to search for several users in one query etc.

Answer (score 1):

A table for each user is a weird approach.

Make a table for ALL users, which is the correct way to go.

Then make a table called `actions` with the `user_id` as a `FOREIGN KEY`, and two more columns: `type` and `time`.

When the user logs in, add a new row to the `actions` table with `type = 1` (login) and when he logs out, add a `type = 2` (logout).

Using numbers instead of strings is better since it reduces database weight.
Repeating the same string is costy.

The `type` column must be a `INT` type.

The time column can have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default value, since it will log the action when it has happened.

[See a example fiddle with schema and query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/376042/7)